# I cant display multiple results (even though the same exact code has worked for me in the past)

Tags: php, mysql

This is super strange.

I used a portion of code for a new project I was working on, and for some reason the results won't display correctly. (They display, just one at a time though)

It worked for me in the past and I really don't get why its not displaying like it should

(Maybe it has to do with the fact I took a yearlong hiatus from coding and PHP 5 is wayyy different from the version I was used to)

Here's the code

```
<?php
$search = $_GET['search'];
$sfrom = $_GET['departure_label'];
$sfromda = $_GET['txtdate1'];
$sto = $_GET['arrival_label'];
$stoda = $_GET['txtdate2'];
$padt = $_GET['ddlPaxADT'];
$pchd = $_GET['ddlPaxCHD'];
$pinf = $_GET['ddlPaxINF'];
$addition = $padt+$pchd+$pinf;
$currency = $_GET['Currency'];

  //connect to database
  mysql_connect("localhost","poop","goldpoop");
  mysql_select_db("moregoldpoop");




  //echo outconstruct
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM search_v WHERE Currency='$currency' AND rout_to='$sto' AND rout_from='$sfrom'ORDER BY date_avialable DESC");
  $runrows = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

   {

    //get data
$flightid = $runrows['flight_id'];
$aseats = $runrows['seats_avialable'];
$todate = strftime("%b %d, %Y %l:%M %p" ,strtotime($runrows['to_date']));
$date = strftime("%b %d, %Y %l:%M %p" ,strtotime($runrows['date_avialable']));
$from = $runrows['rout_from'];
$to = $runrows['rout_to'];
$acost = $runrows['adult_cost'];
$ccost = $runrows['child_cost'];
$cur = $runrows['currency'];
$oth = $runrows['other_cost'];
   echo "";
?>
<li class="item clearfix"> <span
 id="cntntMiddle_ctl01_rptmain_lblFromt_0">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <thead><tr>
        <th class="price">Price</th>
        <th>From</th>
        <th>To</th>
        <th>Depart</th>
      </tr>
      </thead><tfoot> <tr>
        <td><a class="more" href="#">Full
Details</a></td>
        <td colspan="6">
        <div class="select-wrap">
        <p class="seats"><strong><?php echo $aseats; ?></strong> <span>seats
left</span> <em>at this price</em></p>
        <button class="btn-select" type="button"
 onclick='return ray.ajax("#");'>Select Flight</button></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tfoot><tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="price" rowspan="2"><a
 style="font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none;"
 herf="#" onclick='return ray.ajax("#");'><span
 style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $acost; ?></span><span
 style="font-size: 11px; margin-top: 2px; display: block; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-align: center; font-weight: normal;">per
adult</span><span
 style="font-size: 12px; margin-top: 2px; display: block; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-align: center; font-weight: normal;">(with fees)</span></a></td>
          <td><?php echo $from; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $to ?></td>
          <td style="padding-right: 2px;"><?php echo $date; ?></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </span> <a
 id="cntntMiddle_ctl01_rptmain_lblResultDetails1_0" title="1"
 href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cntntMiddle$ctl01$rptmain$ctl00$lblResultDetails1','')"
 style="color: Black;"></a><a class="close"
 href="#">Close</a>
    <div class="info clearfix">
    <div class="info clearfix">
    <h4>Departing Flight</h4>
    <ul class="clearfix">
      <li>
        <h5><?php echo $from; ?> to <?php echo $to; ?> <?php echo $date; ?></h5>
        <ul>
          <li>&nbsp;</li>
          <li><strong>Flight #</strong> - <?php echo $flightid; ?></li>
          <li><strong>Departure Time – </strong>
<?php echo $date; ?></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
      <ul>
        <li style="padding-top: 5px;"><span
 style="color: rgb(212, 22, 13); font-weight: bold; font-size: 11px; text-decoration: none;">
Fare Breakdown</span> </li>
      </ul>
      <table class="more">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>Passenger</th>
            <th>Fare</th>
            <th> Taxes and Fees</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Total Cost</th>
          </tr>
        </tbody><tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Adult</td>
            <td
 style="color: rgb(100, 100, 100); font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $acost; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $oth; ?></td>
            <td id="paxAdtTd">1</td>
            <td><?php echo $acost; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Cost of Sale(<?php echo $cur; ?>)</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td
 style="color: rgb(100, 100, 100); font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $acost; ?></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br />
      <span style="font-weight: bold; padding-top: 10px;">
*Additional airline fees for baggage may apply</span>
      <div class="select-wrap">
      <p class="seats"><strong><?php echo $aseats; ?></strong> <span>seats
left</span> <em>at this price</em></p>
      <button class="btn-select" type="button"
 onclick='return ray.ajax("https://res.com/checkout.aspx?recommendation=1&subset=1&supplier=53&page=flightconfirm",1,this);'>Select
Flight</button></div>
</ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </li>


<?php
}
?>
```

I just wanna know the main reason why it worked before and not now

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the loop? `$runrows = mysql_fetch_array($sql);` should be something like `while ( $runrows = mysql_fetch_array($sql) )`
The loop block is there {} but the loop isn't.

Comment: When I add the loop, nothing displays. So i decided not to use it

Comment: Actually you were right. The reason it didn't display was because I added the ; at the end